# Virto Commerce Cryptographic Exception in azure

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, virtocommerce

After the struggle to successfully deploy virto commerce to Azure, and after activating the email confirmation for new users, I keep running into a Cryptographic Exception:

```
The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
   at VirtoCommerce.Web.Client.Providers.CookieTempDataProvider.Protect(Byte[] data) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Client\CommerceWebClient\Providers\CookieTempDataProvider.cs:line 91
   at VirtoCommerce.Web.Client.Providers.CookieTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 values) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Client\CommerceWebClient\Providers\CookieTempDataProvider.cs:line 28
   at System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Save(ControllerContext controllerContext, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PossiblySaveTempData()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

after googling the exception text, I ran into a few guides hinting that I should set Load User Profile to True in the IIS AppPool, which I tried to do only to find out it was already true by default.

This is one of the sources https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad1f7367-7727-4b1a-a190-840ff4ed5709/adfs-20-sso-the-data-protection-operation-was-unsuccessful?forum=Geneva

EDIT: The exception is thrown when the system generates any token (Account activation, reset password).

Comment: Which version are you using? I believe it was addressed in the latest version (1.13).

Comment: It's the latest version from master of the github repo, version 1.13.

Comment: i was able to replicate the issue and will be providing fix shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated CookieTempDataProvider class, which uses MachineKey instead of ProtectedData to encrypt and decrypt cookies. That should resolve the issue. I'll be rebuilding our test and demo environment and checking if it works. But you can download either the complete source code or just that class and recompile. It should fix the issue you having.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the fix. On a separate note, did you try to redeploy everything to the Azure cloud again? Did it work fine?

Comment: Yes, we updated our demo and it works. The system was using MachineKey everywhere except that one class, must have missed it somehow.

Comment: I'm getting an 404 error, but it seems not to be related with this question...
http://puu.sh/gRHYX/9da9882a17.png
Thanks.

Comment: can you create another ticket outlining the exception in a bit more details? It looks like it can't find the website, which can be caused by stores not configured on the backend

Comment: The value for "DefaultStore" in Web.config was wrong. The value was set to the store name and not the store id. It's solved now.
Thanks